# Eclipse shortcut to switch from currently suspended thread to other suspended thread(s)

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

I have few breakpoints in my java application, all of them suspend different threads at different points. I frequently require switching to another thread by pausing the current thread, is there an eclipse short-cut to do that?

Currently, I go to debug tab and manually click on the top of the stack of the thread I want to switch to.

Comment: I don't think there is such a shortcut.

Comment: You might add shortcuts for the commands _Show View (Debug)_ and _Suspend_: _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_. With _Show View (Debug)_ the focus is transferred to _Debug_ view; use Up/Down to go to the thread and use _Suspend_ to pause or _Resume (F8)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ctrl+Shift+B**

Two years back what I was trying to look for was 'toggle breakpoint', and the default shortcut in Eclipse is Ctrl+Shift+B.